# How to add friction in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to PyGame. I want to make a dodging game which I made it in Scratch 2. Consider a space ship being there flying. You have only Y axis control with up and down keys. When the sprite moves, it should have friction like thing which makes it's Y velocity slow down gradually when up or down keys are pressed

**The Code:**

```
# import sys
from random import randint
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

fps = 60
up = False
down = False
player_location = [250 ,200]
friction = 0.9
force = 4
misy = randint(0, 400)
missile_loc = [590,misy]

player = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
missile = pygame.image.load("missile.png")

Window_size = (600,400)
pygame.display.set_caption("The Game")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(Window_size, 0, 0)

player_rect = pygame.Rect(player_location[0], player_location[1], player.get_width(), player.get_height())
missile_rect = pygame.Rect(missile_loc[0], missile_loc[1], missile.get_width(), missile.get_height())

go = True
while go:

    screen.fill((146, 244, 255))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), player_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), missile_rect)

    player_rect.x = player_location[0]
    player_rect.y = player_location[1]

    # player_location[1] *= friction

    if up == True:
        player_location[1] -= force
    if down == True:
        player_location[1] += force

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            go = False
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                up = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                down = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                up = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                down = False

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What do you mean by friction? Do you mean drag or some imaginary slowing force? [Like this](https://github.com/Spacha/Pygame/blob/master/Friction/original.py)? What should the velocity profile be? First the ship goes fast, then slows down gradually or what?

Comment: Because friction as a force, is often approximated with [F = F_n*mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction), where F_n is the normal force  mu is the frictional coefficient between two sliding surfaces (e.g. spaceship belly and asphalt, ouch) but if it's flying (especially in space), there's no friction per se.

Comment: @Spacha Actually I have coded that line but I have turbed it to comment. Refer the code which I have provided. I tried it and it seemed to the spaceship just sticking to the top of the window.

Comment: I saw that. You had `player_location[1] *= friction`. It makes your `player_location[1]` to be 0.0 in a fraction of a second so that's why it gets stuck in top of the screen. Try the code I provided.

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help me.Actually I found the answer myself after some experiments.

Comment: @SuperByte So please write an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved it myself after some experiments.

**The code:**

```
# import sys
from random import randint
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

fps = 60
up = False
down = False
player_location = [250 ,200]
friction = 0.9
force = 0
misy = randint(0, 400)
missile_loc = [590,misy]

player = pygame.image.load("ship.png")
missile = pygame.image.load("missile.png")

Window_size = (600,400)
pygame.display.set_caption("The Game")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(Window_size, 0, 0)

player_rect = pygame.Rect(player_location[0], player_location[1], player.get_width(), player.get_height())
missile_rect = pygame.Rect(missile_loc[0], missile_loc[1], missile.get_width(), missile.get_height())

go = True
while go:

    screen.fill((146, 244, 255))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), player_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), missile_rect)

    screen.blit(player, player_location)
    screen.blit(missile, missile_loc)

    player_rect.x = player_location[0]
    player_rect.y = player_location[1]

    player_location[1] += force

    force *= friction

    if up == True:
        force -= 1
    if down == True:
        force += 1

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            go = False
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                up = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                down = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                up = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                down = False

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can keep multiplying your velocity by a decimal number (thus simulating friction)
It seem that from your code `force` is your velocity.
So create a variable called 'deceleration = 0.95' the smaller the decimal number the faster the object decelerates.

So in your game loop (preferably at the end for your case) you can multiply your force by the deceleration:

```
force *= deceleration
```

Comment: I don't think this would work as expected (though I'm not entirely sure what is wanted, yet). The force must be reset to the original value on `KEYUP` event. Also, it should be only active when the force is being applied.

Comment: @AntonioKaram I tried it but it seems that the spaceship is getting stuck on the top of the screen. I have cod3d that line bun I turned into comment using #.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, I'm not entirely sure what you want but here is one which gives your spaceship a constant deceleration until it stops. The force returns to normal when the key is released. I'll fix this if you clarify your question.

```py
# import sys
from random import randint
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

fps = 60
up = False
down = False
player_location = [250 ,200]
friction = 0.9
force = 4
misy = randint(0, 400)
missile_loc = [590,misy]

player = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
missile = pygame.image.load("missile.png")

Window_size = (600,400)
pygame.display.set_caption("The Game")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(Window_size, 0, 0)

player_rect = pygame.Rect(player_location[0], player_location[1], player.get_width(), player.get_height())
missile_rect = pygame.Rect(missile_loc[0], missile_loc[1], missile.get_width(), missile.get_height())

drag = 0.0
def vertical_velocity():
    global force, drag
    vel =  force / (drag + 1)
    drag += 0.05
    return vel

go = True
while go:

    screen.fill((146, 244, 255))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), player_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), missile_rect)

    player_rect.x = int(player_location[0])
    player_rect.y = int(player_location[1])

    # player_location[1] *= friction

    if up == True:
        player_location[1] -= vertical_velocity()
    if down == True:
        player_location[1] += vertical_velocity()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            go = False
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                up = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                down = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                up = False
                drag = 0.0
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                down = False
                drag = 0.0

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)

pygame.quit()
```

## Edit

Here's, for example, linear and nonlinear velocity profiles:

```py
drag = 0.0
def vertical_velocity_nonlinear():
    global force, drag
    vel =  force / (drag + 1)
    drag += 0.05
    return vel

def vertical_velocity_linear():
    global force, drag
    vel = force + (1-1/4*drag)
    vel = vel if (vel >= 0) else 0.0
    drag += 0.05
    return vel
```

And the velocity profiles they yield (this is probably not very helpful but here ya go). First is "nonlinear" and second one is "linear".
[image: Velocity profiles]

Answer (score 0):

To move a player, I usually use `x`, `y`, `moveX` and `moveY`.

In this code, the player moves with the arrows, with friction in the left-right movement, and with jump. Simply use the same working for the up-down movement and you can see the player from the top of the scene.

Note that a class is used for the player.

```
pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed() # get the pressed keys

if pressed[K_LEFT]:
    self.moveX -= 3000 * time_passed # time_passed is in seconds
if pressed[K_RIGHT]:
    self.moveX += 3000 * time_passed
if pressed[K_UP]: # jump runs differently
    self.moveY += -1200

self.moveX *= 0.95**(100 * time_passed) # slow down
                                        # 0.95 is friction (moveX *= 0.95 if 100 FPS)

if self.moveY < 1600:
    self.moveY += 5000 * time_passed # go down

self.x += self.moveX * time_passed # add the X movement
self.y += self.moveY * time_passed # add the Y movement
```

Comment: I have answered the solution myself. Just take a look.

Comment: I saw, but I wanted to help you by showing you another way to do that.